# Thumbnails wont show up in the table using sorl-thumbnail within if tags

Tags: django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I try to show images as thumbnails with sorl-thumbnail, but they won't show up... If I use the sorl tag outside of the table, withouth the if tags, they will show up, but as shown below, it doesn't. I see some empty images and when I right-click and view the image I get this message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

    <Error>

    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>

    <Message>Access Denied</Message>

    <RequestId>FB1B90D61EDDABFB</RequestId>

    <HostId>kNOYKLZhcN0N7cgfEfD+bNOs3u4UU2E86gGISMySkNJhobrIA9yFLBh9rgJUbQw+gbyonys5lt8=</HostId>

</Error>
```

When I use the {% thumbnail %} tags outside the table/if statement tags, they will show up... 
I can't find out what might be the cause of this... I work local and have some AWS setup for the live app

Here's the code from the template:

```
{% if list.parent.parent_image %}
        {% if list.image_is_parent %}
    <td>
        {% thumbnail list.parent.parent_image "40x40" as im %}  
        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}
    </td>   

        {% else %}      
        <td><img src="/media/products/assets/no-image.png" class="img-fluid"></td>
        {% endif %}

    {% else %}
        {% if list.image %}
            <td>
        {% thumbnail list.image "40x40" as im2 %}   
                <img src="{{ im2.url }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}  
            </td>   
        {% else %}
            <td><img src="/media/products/assets/no-image.png" class="img-fluid"></td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```